# Jquery Autocomplete limit results with Django

Tags: jquery, django

Using the link- [Jquery Autocomplete with Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6273941/jquery-autocomplete-with-django),
I added django-autocomplete search. Now I want to limit the search results to 5 in the search box. Anyone help me to do that.

Comment: you want to get only five result from database ?  or you want 5 data  show default in jquery autocomplete

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can limit query results:

```
def search_view(request):
    ...
    listado = Model.objects.filter(
                        descripcion__istartswith=q
                                  ).order_by("descripcion")[:5]
    ...
```